# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is required

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

If I change `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` and do gradle sync I get that error.

I am using  gradle plugin version is 3.3.3, gradle JDK version 1.8, and the gradle version is 4.10.1.

I'm working on this to apply crashlytics and I don't know why. please help

cf.

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30

    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'

    playSdkVersion = '8.4.0'
    firebaseVersion = '17.3.4'
    coroutineVersion = '1.0.1'

    imageLoaderSdkVersion = '1.9.3'

    appCompatVersion = '1.0.0'
    recyclerViewVersion = "1.0.0"
    mockitoVersion = "2.28.2"

    lifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
}
```

---

I also get the below error.

```
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'GoogleServicesTask'.
> Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
  Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'GoogleServicesTask'.
```

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException (no error message)
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Answer (score 4):

I upgraded the gradle version as follows and it was solved.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'`

Answer (score 4):

I found this problem I fixed it by upgrading the constraint-layout to the latest version.

androidx

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

android.support

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.

Go To File>>Settings>>Build, Execution, Deployment>Build Tools
And I am enable "Reload project after changes in the build scripts">Any changes.

After this Appeared new Error "Add Google maven repository"
I add Google maven repository to build.gradle and project worked without any errors.

[image]